# C# HttpClient and files generated on the fly

Tags: c#, httpclient

I thought of using HttpClient to download a file (CSV) from a governmental website containing data on crops. However, the issue is that the file is not readily available at the target URL but generated on the fly by the website.

The below code works fine for me with URLs that hold files, but I cannot get it to work with this particular website.

I'm getting the following error for line

```
Stream fileStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(fileUrl);
```

error:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
> at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStreamAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at HttpClientTest.Program.GetFileStream(String fileUrl) in C:\Users\User\source\repos\HttpClientTest\HttpClientTest\Program.cs:line 83

A sample URL to the file is: [CSV file for year 2020](https://rejestrupraw.arimr.gov.pl/krpbducsv?search=&rok=2020&woj=&pow=&gmi=&grupa=&uprawa=&pageNumber=1&pageSize=12)

Any suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HttpClientTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DownloadARiMRData();
        }
 
        private static void DownloadARiMRData()
        {
            int startYear = 2020;
            int endYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
            for (int i = 0; i <= (endYear - startYear); i++)
            {
                string yearValue = (startYear + i).ToString();
                string sourceURL = String.Format("https://rejestrupraw.arimr.gov.pl/krpbducsv?search=&rok={0}&woj=&pow=&gmi=&grupa=&uprawa=&pageNumber=1&pageSize=12", yearValue);
                
                // sample URLs:
                // https://rejestrupraw.arimr.gov.pl/krpbducsv?search=&rok=2020&woj=&pow=&gmi=&grupa=&uprawa=&pageNumber=1&pageSize=12
                // https://rejestrupraw.arimr.gov.pl/krpbducsv?search=&rok=2021&woj=&pow=&gmi=&grupa=&uprawa=&pageNumber=1&pageSize=12
                
                string fileName = String.Format(@"Powierzchnie_upraw_w_gminach_{0}.csv", yearValue);
                string targetDirectory = @"D:\Users\ARiMR\";
                try
                {
                    var task = Task.Run(() => DownloadAndSave(sourceURL, targetDirectory, fileName));
                    task.Wait();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task DownloadAndSave(string sourceFile, string destinationFolder, string destinationFileName)
        {
            Stream fileStream = await GetFileStream(sourceFile);

            if (fileStream != Stream.Null)
            {
                await SaveStream(fileStream, destinationFolder, destinationFileName);
            }
        }

        private static async Task<Stream> GetFileStream(string fileUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                Stream fileStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(fileUrl);
                return fileStream;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Stream.Null;
            }
        }

        private static async Task SaveStream(Stream fileStream, string destinationFolder, string destinationFileName)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(destinationFolder))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationFolder);

            string path = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, destinationFileName);

            using (FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await fileStream.CopyToAsync(outputFileStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give some more informations about: "I cannot get it to work"? Do you have error messages?

Comment: Sure, sorry, I have updated the original post.

Comment: You use the network tab in your browser to find out what a real browser does when you click the link, e.g. does it get sent a redirect, or a page with some javascript on that starts the download, or does it get a "click here to get your file" landing page etc.. And you use HttpClient to mimick that with a series of calls etc. HttpClient is not a browser, it fetches data via HTTP but that's all. If further work is required to follow a trail of breadcumbs to the gingerbread house, you gotta write that I'm afraid

Comment: 403 means you are missing some authentication somewhere. You need to find out how the website requires authenticationas there are a number of methods. Almost all the code you show is not relevant to the quesiton, but side notes: Use `async Task Main` and use `await` all the way through rather than `Task.Run` and `.Wait`. The `stream` needs to be in a `using` to dispose it.